# Animated Bar Chart with SVG and CSS (D3 & svelte)

Tags: d3.js, svelte

I want to make an animated bar chart with scroller. I already made the scroll and the data interactivity, but I stuck at the transition.

I use the CSS transition on each `<g>` element. While it's animating and moving toward the right direction, they start at nowhere/or center(?), but not from the last position. I made the data key `consectetur` to be always the largest every time, so it is supposed to be always on top of the chart. But it's always animating from the center or the bottom, not staying on top.

```
<svg>
{#each data as d}
<!--translate Y reactive to data changes -->
<g class="gBar" transform="translate(0 {d.id * 10})">
  <text>Lorem ipsum</text>
  <!--rect width reactive to data changes -->
  <rect x="0" y="0"
        width={d.val/max * w * 0.5} 
        height="10" 
        fill="black"/>
</g>
{/each}
</svg>

<style>
/* add transition to the gBar class */
.gBar {
   transition:transform 1s;
}
</style>
```

I tried the svelte transition directive, but a bit confused to trigger it with the `index` change by the scroller. (The example of transition directive is using boolean checkbox)

This is what I already made:
https://svelte.dev/repl/099ac842d7a54ab7a674545f8dc6d622?version=3.53.1

Comment: Please create a *minimal* example illustrating your problem and include all relevant code in the question itself (not just a link).

Comment: @H.B. example added, hope it's clear

Comment: That is not self-contained, as it references multiple variables that are not defined. It is also probably not representative and does not show how the data is modified, which would cause the transition.